# Loop in file, extract file name, add name to table, repeat flow on each file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis

**ANSWER BELOW**

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct flow to import each file in a folder, extract the file name, run a script on the file name to use only a portion of the file name, then insert into a master table.

I have all the pieces I need: I'm able to loop through all the files with a Foreach loop and take the file name as a variable. Inside the Foreach container is a Data Flow Task to import the records from a flat file to a SQL table. Move out of the loop and my next step is to run a script to get the part of the file name that I need. Then the last step is a SQL query to run some transformations and move the records to a MasterStageFinal table.

The issue I'm having is the Foreach loop runs each step an equal number of times to the enumerator instead of running each step once and running the entire sequence per enumeration.

So for example, in the folder I have two files, one with 250 records, one with 500. My current flow will insert 1500 records into the database (imports both files twice because of the enumeration) and all with the part number from only one of the files.

So, how would I best solve this?

[image]

Foreach Loop Properties

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed your code instead. Your explanation is ok, but you may be missing something in the translation.

Comment: if you want to run the script task for each loop then include that into foreach

Comment: Best way to debug such stuff is by using `Exec Script Task` in for-each loop and print the variables before run: eg: `MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::variableName"].Value.ToString());`

Comment: Please show screenshots of your foreach loop properties.   Sounds like you set it up wrong.\

Comment: @TabAlleman added a screenshot of the properties.

Comment: @siddharthajain the loop would still pull both files first, then run the script, thus only pulling in one part number rather than both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer thanks to this site. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Here is my final flow. The Flat File Source uses a connection string initiated by the Foreach Loop of the file name/location.

[image]